# How to connect server from the given IP address in Android

Tags: android, image, upload, ip-address

i am working on Assignment of Image Upload to Server in android i have done upto some extend but leftwith

"Where to Place the Image to be Uploaded in Which Folder ?"

"How to Connect to server with the given IP address so that i can Upload image on that server"?.

if anyone require any more clarification on this from me,Please let me Know,can any body provide me with help on similar link on this.

Thanking in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may put the file you want to upload to `"files"` directory of your app, for example. You get this dir with [`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) method.
2. [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) shows how to upload data to server.